# Generation a simplify list from a list of duplicate arrays in Php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, duplicates

For example here is my list of orders:

```
Cup red --------> 2
TV-1 -----------> 1
TV-1 -----------> 1
Table ----------> 1
Table ----------> 1
Cup white ------> 1 
Cup white ------> 3
Cup green ------> 4
```

Expected result:

```
Cup red --------> 2
TV-1 -----------> 2
Table ----------> 2
Cup white ------> 4
Cup green ------> 4
```

Can you show  me your ideas or any same issues?

Comment: take a look at [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Can you show how your array is actually set up.

Comment: where is that type of array coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your source array looks like this:

```
$arr = [
    ['Cup red' => 2], ['TV-1' => 1], ['TV-1' => 1], ['Table' => 1], ['Table' => 1], ['Cup white' => 1],
    ['Cup white' => 3], ['Cup green' => 4],
];
```

Then you could use:

```
$keyStore = [];
foreach($arr as $record) {
    foreach($record as $key => $value) {
        $keyStore[$key] = $key;
    }
}

$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $key0 => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $item) {
        if (in_array($key1, $keyStore)) {
            $result[$key1] = isset($result[$key1]) ? $result[$key1] += $item : $result[$key1] = $item;
        }
    }
}
```

Output `print_r($result)`:
Array

```
(
    [Cup red] => 2
    [TV-1] => 2
    [Table] => 2
    [Cup white] => 4
    [Cup green] => 4
)
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/q7NCt)

Answer (score 1):

If we assume your list is an array of arrays:

```
$array = [
    ['Cup red' => 2],
    ...
];
```

You can do this with Collection methods pretty easily:

```
collect($array)->mapToGroups(fn ($i) => $i)
    ->map->sum()
    ->all()
```

After `mapToGroups` you have a structure like:

```
[
    'Cup red' => [2],
    'Cup white' => [1, 3],
    ...
]
```

Then you can use `map` to iterate through each of these to get the sums.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods):

- [`mapToGroups`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-maptogroups)
- [`map`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map)
- [`sum`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sum)